# Installing C++ Armadillo library on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, lapack, blas, armadillo

I am trying to use the C++ armadillo library (armadillo-0.9.10) on a Mac Pro.  I follow the manual installation instruction in the README.txt file.  I have modified the config.hpp file to indicate that I have LAPACK and BLAS installed. I then try to compile the examples.  I successfully compile and run example1.cpp, but when I try to run example2.cpp it reports that I need to have ATLAS or LAPACK installed.  I added the #include  header to example2.cpp and use the -framework Accelerate flag to compile in the makefile.  However, it is still not working.  What gives?  I should have LAPACK and BLAS installed by default with Xcode, no?  Any help here would be wonderful.  Thank you, thank you!

Comment: Just for anyone else who happens upon this.  I solved the problem (sort of).  I downloaded the cmake utility and installed it that way instead of trying to do it manually.  Using cmake it found BLAS, LAPACK, and Boost and automatically updated the config.hpp file.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

I'm trying to get the example1.cpp file to run but I can't seem to get it to run in Xcode.

I also followed the instructions in the README.txt file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure if You are still trying to figure this out or now but to answer your original question, you can easily download and setup Armadillo from the website: http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html

I would rather use home brew instead:

```
brew install armadillo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try homebrew. it will install necessary packages and save your time

```
brew install homebrew/science/armadillo
```

Comment: If you are going to add an answer, you need to give a proper explanation--not just type a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer above this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26175742/6394722) returns that: Error: homebrew/science was deprecated,
I search for this error and find solution, and it works for me. Try this:

```
brew install brewsci/science/armadillo
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/nest/nest-simulator/issues/916)